# byobu: can I predefine a layout with window sizes etc?

Tags: byobu

I am just starting with byobu and can't figure out this basic thing.  I need to set up a predefined layout for my windows in byobu so when I start it, I get the layout I predefined and my programs start in the windows.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

Sure, it's quite easy using [Byobu's](http://byobu.co) built in hotkeys.

Create the layout however you want, using:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to split vertically
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to split horizontally
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up/Down/Left/Right</kbd> to move around the splits
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up/Down/Left/Right</kbd> to resize each split

Until you're happy with the layout.

Then, you can save the layout using: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>.

And you can restore the layout using: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Also note that  you can see all of Byobu's hotkeys using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thanks Dustin.  Byobu seems very simple and easy to use compared to others I have tried.  I would like to start Byobu and have my commands launched in the correct window.  Is this possible?

Comment: if i may suggest here, it would be awesome to have some layout-balancing procedure in `byobu`! nice package anyways.

Comment: @DaveK it's possible with [some tmux magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5752901/4970442), using tmux as backend (default). JFTR layouts are saved on `~/.byobu/layouts/`.

Comment: Should this work for all windows or only the current one? For me it seems only to save the current window..